# pandas: efficiently adding the values of two (time) series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two (larger than the toy example) Series e.g.:

```
s1 = pd.read_json('{"count":{"1614470400000":4,"1617148800000":0,"1619740800000":0,"1622419200000":4,"1625011200000":4,"1627689600000":5,"1630368000000":0,"1632960000000":8,"1635638400000":2}}')['count']
s2 = pd.read_json('{"count":{"1625011200000":1}}')['count']
```

What would be an efficient way to add them?
I can imagine creating a join, then adding  ignoring nans, but I think this should be slower than some operation that would merge sort them?

Here is the desired result for the toy example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [Series.add(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) using the parameter **fill_value=0**

```
out = s1.add(s2,fill_value=0)
            count
2019-06-30    1.0
2021-02-28    4.0
2021-03-31    0.0
2021-04-30    0.0
2021-05-31    4.0
2021-06-30    4.0
2021-07-31    5.0
2021-08-31    0.0
2021-09-30    8.0
2021-10-31    2.0
```

Comment: this is cleaner than my example and would sum the values correctly if dates were similar across series, as I pointed out in my post. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Thnx, had not seen Series gives you add out of the box, I tried s1+s2 but that gives nans. I still wonder if someone could time it vs. an optimized merge sort, but since its part of the library, Its more than good for me right now!

Answer (score 1):

Below works but I really don't know how you are adding june 30 2019 and june 30 2021 together to get 5. I had to change 2019 to 2021 to make it work.

```
s3 = pd.concat([s1,s2])
s3.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Comment: Ooops! thats the difference between using python and a spreadsheet to produce the result ;)